Compute $\Pr(Y=y| X=x \vee X=\bar{x})$ from $\Pr(Y=y| X=x)$ and $\Pr(Y=y| X=\bar{x})$
Consider two random variables, $X$ and $Y$ discrete for simplicity. Suppose, I know
$$
(*)\quad \Pr(Y=y| X=x) \quad \forall x
$$
and I want to compute
$$
(**) \Pr(Y=y| X=x \vee X=\bar{x}) 
$$
It is clear that $(*)$ is not sufficient to compute $(**)$. However, I am wondering if $(*)$ is useful at all and what else I would need.
Simply considering the formula for the conditional probability, we have:
$$
\Pr(Y=y| X=x \vee X=\bar{x}) =\frac{\Pr(Y=y, X=x \vee X=\bar{x}) }{\Pr(X=x \vee X=\bar{x})}=\frac{\Pr(Y=y, X=x \vee X=\bar{x}) }{\Pr(X=x)+ \Pr( X=\bar{x})}.
$$
Therefore, knowing
$$
\Pr(X=x), \Pr(X=\bar{x})
$$
seems necessary. How about the numerator $\Pr(Y=y, X=x \vee X=\bar{x})$? Can it be somehow obtained from $\Pr(Y=y| X=x \vee X=\bar{x})$?

Hint: $(X=x)$ and $(X=\bar x)$ are disjoint events and so the numerator is the sum of $\Pr(Y=y, X=x)$ and $\Pr(Y=y,X=\bar x)$. Do you know, or can you compute, these probabilities from the given information? If not, what additional information do you need?

Then, following your hint, I think I only need $\Pr(X=x)$ and $\Pr(X=\bar{x})$.
